# Protect my service from taskkiller-apps

Tags: android, service

I am developing an application that needs to constantly run a service unless the user consciously deactivates it. The problem is that there are taskkiller-apps with a "kill all applications"-button. These seem to become increasingly popular, and they are causing me a fuzz. When I kill my service with som task managers, onDestroy() is never run and all AlarmManagers are killed with the service. Is there any way to protect my service from these apps, or to restart my service immediately after it is killed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to protect my service
>   from these apps, or to restart my
>   service immediately after it is
>   killed?

Not really, sorry.

Besides, if your service is well-behaved (i.e., not designed to run in memory all of the time), users will be less likely to kill it off using these tools. [Services are not designed to run forever](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/).

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Unfortunately more and more task managers are adding the "kill all"-button to make it easier for users to free up memory, so users might kill my service by mistake. My current solution is to have a constant notification that shows when the service is running (this can ofcourse be turned off in the settings-menu). Hopefylly then the user will detect if the notification disappears.

Comment: Yeah sorry this is unfortunate.  Froyo will address the issue, but I realize it will be a while before this will generally help developers.

Comment: Hello, Mark. Could you suggest a btter way then "mortal" service to keep a track from sensors and location manager and send it to the server?

Comment: @WinteWinte: Design it to deal with the fact that it can go away at any point, such as by user request. Or, build your own version of Android that incorporates your desired changes, and use that on whatever devices that you can.

Comment: Actually I have faced with issue of app architecture without this factor in mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531304/android-how-to-avoid-null-in-intent-that-i-have-got-in-service. I don't understand the whole sequence of events that lead my service to be killed and recreated because I haven't get any calbacks such as onTrimMemory, onLowMemory, onDestroy (I put in Log.d(msg)). I just get an null intent and I decide to silent close the app but better to handle this event and continue work. Could you be so helpfull to suggest a source where I can read a more about this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, using "Advanced Task Manager" for Android. The app even has an "exlude list" where you can protect your apps from being killed by the Task Manager.
But still, my service would be killed, leaving it useless. I've been through loads of forums, trying to contact the author of ATM, but to no avail.

The solution (sounds like a bug in ATM): I had to exclude the service as well as the app that started the service in ATM to make it leave my app untouched (even though only the service was needed). Weird, but true.