# how to avoid null in intent that I have got in Service?

Tags: android, service

I have a service that works in background. He returns START_STICKY because it listens to some events, this events occurs very fast (data from sensors). I some cases my service is killed: I have got a null intent and according to documentation it can happens when my service has killed because his process go away.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

I want to know how avoid it. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update**

```
    private void startForeground() {
    String title = "Warning";//getString(R.string.note_title);
    String text = "App still working";//getString(R.string.note_msg);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DriverActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);


    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(pending);

    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: Thanks. I would kepp in mind this advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs you need to identify why your service terminates. The two most probable motives are:

- Service trows an exception and was terminated by Android
- Service was terminated by Android because was running for long time (usually between 30 minutes and 1 hour) without being stated as foreground service

**Exception**
This type of problem you can easly identify looking at logcat. Correction will depend on the cause reported.

**Foreground**
this you can solve by setting your service to foreground using:

```
        startForeground(message, notification);
```

in your service.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, Luis. I implemented what you suggested and now I am testing it. I have a question: I exepect that my notification would be in tray when go away from my working app but I never saw it. I did something similar what we can see in <urphy's code https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Notifications/FakePlayer/src/com/commonsware/android/fakeplayerfg/PlayerService.java Do are my expectations wrong?

Comment: Your expectations are correct. The notification setup in that example is deprecated, but should work. I fact, when you start a service in foreground mode, the notification can't be demissed at all, to ensure that user is aware that the service is running.

Comment: Luis, I don't see the ison in tray. I update my question so you can see code, this method run when I get a command in service. Could you tell what wrong with it?